# If a server is lagging, why is a sound made when blocks are broken, but not placed?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have a server I have access to via SSH. I compiled craftbukkit and am now running Craftbukkit 1.8.3 on the server. I started the Minecraft server, but I wanted to do some other stuff in the terminal, so I pressed Ctrl + Z, and backgrounded the process. The server then timed out, but I noticed, when a server times out, you can still break blocks, but the information won't be sent to the server. But, if you break blocks, you still hear the noise of the block being broken. However, when you place blocks, you don't hear the noise of the block being placed. Why does this happen?

Comment: Could it be the way the block-breaking and block-placing code was written?

Comment: Why is it marked as off-topic? (The Minecraft Source code is open for anyone to look at)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your server times out block updates are no longer sent.

There are no block updates on destroy block commands until the corresponding item inside the block (ore/cobblestone) is dropped, or the player with moderator hulk fists removes it's presence from the data stream of the server.

But placing blocks results in an immediate block update call, which cannot happen since the server has timed out, since the code has probably been written so that the sound plays on success or something similar, that's where you get the issue.

Or so I believe.

Correct me if there's a more appropriate answer.

P.S.: Why are you wondering about this, does it have significance to you specifically?

Comment: It doesn't really have any significance, I was simply wondering about Minecraft mechanics. Thanks for the good answer, +1'd and selected. :)